# How to display a string for a certain time on Form or PictureBox without using DrawString() method or MessageBox() in C#

Tags: c#, timer, drawing, graphics2d, thread-sleep

I tried to display a string using `DrawString()` method in `onPaint()` method depending on a flag in another method periodically ... 
I failed to display it correctly as it appears then disappears quickly!!.

Is there any other way i.e. without using `DrawString()` or `MessageBox()`, in order to display or draw such a message.

Note that I used `Thread.Sleep()`!.

Inside `onPaint()` :

```
 if(auvSend == true) {

                base.OnPaint(e);



                g.DrawString("Received Aggrigated Data from AUV # " + auv[auvSenderID].auvID, font,auvSendMsg, 500, 36); // Display that the sink receive data from the AUV

                MessageBox.Show("Received Aggrigated Data from AUV # " + auv[auvSenderID].auvID);

                player.Play();

                Thread.Sleep(3000);             

                g.DrawImage(new Bitmap("C:/temp/temp.png"), 500, 36, 196, 16);// clear

                player.Stop();

                auv[auvSenderID].queue1.Clear();

                auvSend = false;



            }
```

I check an array list if it contains a specific number to change the value of the flag in a background do work method:

```
if (moveBtnIsClicked == false && movebtnGeneticIsClicked == false )
                    {

                        if (auv[0].queue1.Count == 10) 
                        {


                            foreach (Packet packet in auv[0].queue1)
                            {
                                auv[0].SendToSink(packet);
                            }


                            auvSenderID = 0;

                            auvSend = true;

                            topology.Invalidate();                         


                        }



                         if (auv[1].queue1.Count == 10) 
                        {


                            foreach (Packet packet in auv[1].queue1)
                            {
                                auv[1].SendToSink(packet);
                            }

                            auvSenderID = 1;


                            auvSend = true;

                            topology.Invalidate();


                        }


                         if (auv[2].queue1.Count == 10) 
                        {


                            foreach (Packet packet in auv[2].queue1)
                            {
                                auv[2].SendToSink(packet);
                            }


                            auvSenderID = 2;

                            auvSend = true;

                            topology.Invalidate(); 


                        }


                         if (auv[3].queue1.Count == 10) 
                        {


                            foreach (Packet packet in auv[3].queue1)
                            {
                                auv[3].SendToSink(packet);
                            }


                            auvSenderID = 3;

                            auvSend = true;

                            topology.Invalidate();




                        }


                    }
```

Comment: _Is there any other way i.e. __without__ using DrawString()_ Why? Because you failed at your first attempt? Why not use a Timer?

Comment: I used Thread.Sleep(3000) !!

Comment: I know. But I don't know how your Draw code looked. Nor which thread you made wait. The UI thread? A bad idea to freeze the program..

Comment: @TaW : I've update my question, kindly provide me by answer

Comment: Where does `g` come from? Where does this code coem from? If it is a Paint/OnPaint event, why not draw with the e.Graphics obejct??

Comment: IMHO, the most obvious way to do this is place a `Label` object on the form where you want the text to display, with the `Visible` property `false`. Then, in an `async` method, when you want to show it, set the `Text` property to whatever you want to show, set the `Visible` property to `true`, `await Task.Delay(...);` for however long you want it to show, and then set the `Visible` property back to `false`. There's not enough context in your question to be able to be more specific than that, never mind post an actual answer, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  : yes this is what I need, I tried something similar by my self but using timer and did not work... kindly post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough context in your question to provide an answer that is tailored to your specific need. However, I believe that the basic approach you're using is fundamentally wrong. I.e. there does not appear to be a reason to put the code in the `OnPaint()` method, and doing so will block the UI thread, and in the middle of a redraw for that matter (so, doubly wrong).

Assuming you have a button that initiates the action (called, for example, `button1`), and a label on the form where you want to display the text (called, for example, `label1`) something like this would work:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Received Aggregated Data from AUV # " + auv[auvSenderID].auvID
    label1.Visible = true;
    player.Play();
    await Task.Delay(3000);             
    label1.Visible = false;
    player.Stop();
    auv[auvSenderID].queue1.Clear();
    auvSend = false;
}
```

Lacking context, I don't know what `player` is, nor whether the `Play()` and/or `Stop()` methods complete quickly or not. But assuming those are immediately-returning methods, the above will set the text, show the label, call the `Play()` method, and then wait three seconds *without blocking the UI thread*, and then hide the label, call the `Stop()` method, etc. once the wait has completed.

If you are doing all this in response to something other than a user clicking a button, you can do the same basic thing, but just in a different method (i.e. not a `Click` event handler). Just call that method when you want to initiate the text display, etc.

Comment: But the change in the label I need depends on an if statement not button click !!

Comment: _"the change in the label I need depends on an if statement not button click "_ -- like I already wrote in my answer:  _"If you are doing all this in response to something other than a user clicking a button, you can do the same basic thing"_. You didn't bother to provide a good [mcve], so I can't tell you _exactly_ how you'd do that; but the general idea is, where your `if` statement is, you call a method that works just like the `Click` event handler I've shown above. The most obvious difference in specifics being that in another method, you can forego the `sender` and `e` parameters.